# Difference between IE Standard, Compatible & Quirks

Tags: html, meta-tags, meta

I have gone throught many Solutions in stackoverflow but was not able to get. please anyone explain me in simple words

1) what is basic difference between IE Standard, Compatible, Quirks mode and how does it matters?
2) I want to force Webpage to load in IE7 in IE9 Browser ... is my below code correct?

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=IE7" />
```

IE=IE7 > Standard Mode

IE=EmulateIE7 > Compatible Mode

how to run in Quirks Mode

3) Is this modes applicable to browsers other IE?
4) What is default mode of Browser and how do i determine it?

Answer (score 1):

First, you really don't want to be doing this - preferably run IE9 as IE9, even better, use IE 10/11, even better use Chrome, MS Edge etc.

But, assuming you are forced into it, your Meta tag should say content="IE=7"

This *should* force IE7 Standards mode and at least make everything consistent between IE7 and IE9 (well, it should, but there may still be anomalies). If there are you may need to detect IE9 and use EmulateIE7, but, again, this may cause more problems than it solves.

And, these modes only apply to IE - all other browsers ignore them.

And, you really don't want me to explain the difference between Standard, Compatible, and Quirks mode, partly because it would take 57 hours and partly because I've forgotten.

Good luck ...

Comment: IE=IE7 > Standard Mode ....... IE=EmulateIE7 > Compatible Mode .... quirks mode syntax?

Comment: And I should have said all the before is dependent on:

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">